# Field name has a space in it

Tags: google-apps-script

I made a script in apps script to access an API on oil price data from the Alberta government. There's a problem with the API key code where the **Type** field has a space at the end of it and the script isn't recognizing the data to pull and just coming out blank.

Example:

> {"Date":"1983-08-01T00:00:00","Type ":"WTI","Unit":"$US/bbl","Value":31.88}

```
function fetchOilPrices() { 
  var sheetName = 'Oil Prices';
  
  // Check if the sheet with the name already exists  
  var existingSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName); 
  if (!existingSheet) { 
    
  // If it does not exist, create a new sheet tab with the specific name    
  var newSheet = spreadsheet.insertSheet(sheetName); } 
  else { 
  
  // If it exists, assign it to newSheet    
  newSheet = existingSheet; } 
    
  var url = "https://api.economicdata.alberta.ca/api/data?code=0d593867-2089-4514-8901-9e2d7f666e0c"; 
  var options = {
      "method": "get",
  }; 
       
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options); 
  var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); 
    
  // Assuming the data is in an array  
  var observations = data; 
  var recentData = [["Date", "Type", "Value"]]; // Headers for the sheet  
    
  // Loop through observations and extract the necessary fields **Here's where I'm having issues** 
  observations.forEach(function(obs) { 
    recentData.push([obs.Date, obs.Type , obs.Value]);  
  }); 
  
  // Reverse the order of the data (excluding the header)  
  recentData = [recentData[0]].concat(recentData.slice(1).reverse()); 
  
  // Clear the sheet  
  newSheet.clearContents(); 
  Logger.log(sheetName + " cleared.") 
  
  // Write the data to the sheet  
  newSheet.getRange(1, 1, recentData.length, 3).setValues(recentData); 
  Logger.log("Written data for " + observations.length + " observations.");
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried using bracket notation which is `obs['Type ']` instead?

Comment: Works! I tried that before but didn't take out the period. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use JavaScript Object Bracket Notation Instead

If I understood your post correctly, you had issues calling the object property `Type`  since you were using `Dot Notation` for calling the property value. Instead, you may use `Bracket Notation` by changing:

```
recentData.push([obs.Date, obs.Type , obs.Value]);
```

to

```
recentData.push([obs.Date, obs['Type '], obs.Value]);
```

### Test Case

I have tried the following script below:

```
function test() {
  var object = {
    'ID': 1,
    'Type ': 'testType'
  }
  console.log(object.ID, object['Type '])
}
```

And got the following output:

[image]

### References

You may refer to these articles:

- [Property Accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)
- [Dot Notation vs Bracket Notation for Object Properties – What's the Difference?](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/dot-notation-vs-square-brackets-javascript/)

---